# Использование единой базы данных для кроссплатформенного мобильного приложения и веб-сайта. Как реализовать?

Tags: c#, база-данных, xamarin, кроссплатформенность

Работаю эникейщиком в небольшой фирме. Появилась необходимость создать кросплатформенное мобильное приложение и сайт типа "доска объявлений". 
Так как я работал не много на c# решил делать приложение с помощью xamarin. Для меня самое сложное (так как я никогда с этим не работал, но есть время на изучение) - это создание и управление общей базой данных. Посоветуйте пожалуйста как это все реализовать в общих чертах и подкиньте информации по этой теме. Спасибо!

Comment: При работе над дипломом я делал так: нашёл бесплатный хост с phpMyAdmin(да не закидают меня камнями), написал серверную часть сайта на php для получения записей из БД и сериализации их в JSON, в C# получал эту строку путём запроса к странице и десериализовывал с помощью json.NET. Но как по мне этот вариант на крайний случай.

Comment: Как и написали выше, для таких целей создается "центральный" сервер, который по средствам API (XML/JSON), либо WCF сервиса делится данными по запросу между всеми пользователями. Создав такой сервер - вам достаточно будет отправить запрос и прочитать без труда нужные данные.

Comment: [Книги по C# и другая литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/213987)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Серверную часть можно развернуть на [ASP.NET Core](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/) общение с мобильным приложением (и web фронтом если решите делать Single Page Application (SPA)) по [Web API](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/). Для связи с базой данных можно использовать ORM например [Entity Framework](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/) или [LinqToDB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) они поддерживают различные базы данных.

Клиентскую часть (SPA) можно написать на JavaScript используя фреймворки типа [Angular](https://metanit.com/web/angular2/) или [React](https://metanit.com/web/react/). Для кроссплатформенного мобильного приложения можно использовать [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) для Angular тоже должно что-то быть. Ну или [Xamarin](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/) как вы уже указали.

Comment: Вы предлагаете эникею, который БД не умеет создавать, заделаться фуллстеком и написать в одного всё это?

Comment: Это не я давал такое задание эникею, я всего лишь предложил самое простое на мой взгляд решение, для человека который знаком с C#

Comment: Так я не про задание говорю, а про решение. Мне оно совсем не кажется простым. Не кажется, потому что я сейчас хобби проект делаю на EF + ASP.NET Core 2 + Angular - и это все не так просто, а эникею имхо неподъемно.

Comment: А что по вашему просто, где нужен сайт с базой + мобильное приложение? И знание только C#

Comment: Просто - ничего. Проще - это выяснить конкретные требования и от них плясать. Так как мне, например, не ясно, для чего им мобильное приложение, если будет сайт с тем же контентом. Может оно и не нужно совсем. Может им просто вордпресс подойдет и прогаммить ничего не надо. Но вообще задача эникею программить уже многое говорит о способах постановки задач в компании.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к tym32167. Пипиливаю порой pet-проект на .net core - и могу сказать, что решение можно упростить. Пусть сначала соберут хотя бы сайт и без ангуляра, а потом уже думают о мобильном приложении.

Comment: Человек спросил "Посоветуйте пожалуйста как это все реализовать в общих чертах и подкиньте информации по этой теме." Собственно я и посоветовал.

Comment: ну мы здесь и обсуждаем ваш совет, это же комментарии под ним :)

Comment: На C# - ASP.NET Core - самый простой и удобный путь, без WebAPI сложно сделать мобильное приложение. ReactNative легче чем Xamarin имхо, почти тот же код можно использовать и для веб морды. Сложно не спорю, но какое задание - такое и решение.

Comment: Потому я и сомневаюсь в постановке задачи и в самой задаче. Зачем ему мобильное приложение? Может оно и не нужно тут. А если не нужно, то и WEB.API не нужно, как и SPA. Может, можно обойтись связкой ASP.NET MVC + БД, а может и вообще что то готовое найти и поставить - и программить не надо :)